# Tool to lint passwd and group files

Tags: passwd

Recently I fixed a problem caused by duplicate entries in `/etc/passwd` on Linux.  To catch it sooner next time I plan to do some basic sanity checks on the file each day, one of which will be that no duplicate uids are found.

But surely this is something many others have done and there is already a well-known tool to lint the `passwd` and `group` files for errors?  I appreciate it is only a couple of lines of perl, but before reinventing the wheel I feel I should check.  Does such a program exist?

Comment: vipw and vigr may be what you want.

Comment: Iain, how do you mean?  I don't see in the vipw documentation any discussion of how it sanity-checks the file.

Comment: They sanity check the files in exit [tag:suck-it-and-see]

Comment: @Iain: I've no problems adding and saving a completely bogus `/etc/passwd` entry with `vipw` on Ubuntu and CentOS.

Comment: Nope, vipw does no such sanity check, at least not on Fedora 20.  (I thought you might be referring to the way they lock the files to avoid concurrent edits - which would sometimes avoid duplicate entries being added, though not in this case.)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look into `pwck` and `grpck`.

It's in `shadow-utils` on RedHat based systems and `passwd` on Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: pwck does some useful checks, but not this one.  You can have two users with the same uid and it does not complain.  But I guess pwck is the logical place to add further checks.